# Set Width For Each Column In Grid - Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I try to set width to each column on grid. But It was throw Null pointer exception.
My coding :

```
for(Column column : grid.getColumns()){<br>
            System.out.println(column.getHeaderCaption());<br>
            grid.getColumn(column.getHeaderCaption()).setWidth(100);<br>
}
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vaadin.reports.ViewImpl.init(ViewClass.java:134)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the `column.getHeaderCaption()` the identifier of your columns?
Otherwise of course it won't give you back the column for `grid.getColumn(...)`

Comment: Thank you Marton.. I can change my coding.. It was working well

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in my coding follow:

```
for(Column column : grid.getColumns()){
System.out.println(column.getPropertyId().toString());
grid.getColumn(column.getPropertyId().toString()).setWidth(Double widthSize);
}
```

It was working well:-)